# Regex to replace invalid characters

Tags: c#, regex

I don't have much experience with RegEx so I am using many chained String.Replace() calls to remove unwanted characters -- is there a RegEx I can write to streamline this?

```
string messyText = GetText();
string cleanText = messyText.Trim()
         .ToUpper()
         .Replace(",", "")
         .Replace(":", "")
         .Replace(".", "")
         .Replace(";", "")
         .Replace("/", "")
         .Replace("\\", "")
         .Replace("\n", "")
         .Replace("\t", "")
         .Replace("\r", "")
         .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
         .Replace(" ", "");
```

Thanks

Comment: Even if it's not your preferred coding convention, if you would put each `.Replace()` on a new line, it would help readability on this site so there wouldn't be a big horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\s,:.;/\\]+");
string cleanText = regex.Replace(messyText, "").ToUpper();
```

`\s` is a character class equivalent to `[ \t\r\n]`.

---

If you just want to preserve alphanumeric characters, instead of adding every non-alphanumeric character in existence to the character class, you could do this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\W_]+");
string cleanText = regex.Replace(messyText, "").ToUpper();
```

Where `\W` is any non-word character (not `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

Comment: `\s` also contains `\v` and `\f`, but those aren't that commonly used, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: do you need RegexOptions.Multiline or will your regex handle it?

Comment: @Preet I believe `RegexOptions.Multiline` only affects the behavior of start and end of string anchors `^` and `$`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: turns out the second option is what I'm *really* looking for

Answer (score 2):

[Character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes) to the rescue!

```
string messyText = GetText();
string cleanText = Regex.Replace(messyText.Trim().ToUpper(), @"[,:.;/\\\n\t\r ]+", "")
```

Comment: @kevingessner: use @"..." or your \t \r \n will get turned into their whitespace equiv.s by .NET. Or escape them but I think @ is more readable.

Comment: @quantumSoup, @Dinah: You don't need to escape them or use `@` - the whitespace equivalents will match just fine. Although generally it *is* a good idea to use verbatim strings with regexes. But not necessary here. And of course his code *does* replace backslashes (the only character he (correctly) *did* escape).

Comment: @Tim It does now, but not without the verbatim string.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: good point; my mistake. @kevingessner: since you're replacing all of the spaces, you don't need `Trim()`. Also, space, \n, \t, and \r can be collectively replaced with \s as Rogue did.

Comment: @quantumSoup: You're right, the `\\` wouldn't have worked in a non-verbatim string. It's late here, and I should be in bed...

Comment: @Tim If he didn't want to use verbatim strings, he could have used one more backslash, ie: `"[,:.;/\\\\n\t\r ]+"`, then we have 3 backslashes to match a single literal backslash, but that's just too damn ugly.

Comment: @quantumSoup: He would even have needed five backslashes - the fifth one for `\n`...

Comment: @quantumSoup: good catch. It took me a second to figure it out. For anyone else who couldn't figure it out: you need the 2 backslashes to be passed to the regex engine so the engine recognizes it as an escaped backslash. In the original version .NET interpreted as an escaped backslash (ie: 1 backslash) before passing it to the regex engine. To use the non @ version, 4 would have been needed just for the backslash match.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use a whitelist approach, there is an ocean of funny characters whose effect depending on combination may not be easy to figure.

A simple regex that removes everything but the allowed characters could look like this:

```
messyText = Regex.Replace(messyText, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\x7C\x2C\x2E_]", "");
```

The ^ is there to invert the selection, apart from the alphanumeric characters this regex allows | , . and _ You can add and remove characters and character sets as needed.