# .NET char array comparison

Tags: c#, char

I have the following c# method to get a valid file name out of a proposed name:

```
public static string GetValidFilename(string fileNameCandidate)
{
    var invalids = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
    var _name = fileNameCandidate.ToCharArray();
    var validName = _name.Except(invalids).ToArray();
    return new string(validName);
}
```

What I expected was the original name with any invalid characters from invalids removed.  However, what I get is original name with invalid filename characters and others removed.
For example, if I called the method with "ems:almcc_srr_view" as input parameter, I expected "emsalmcc_srr_view as output.  What I get is "emsalc_rviw" as output.   What did I  miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the fact that [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) is a *set* operation. In other words, it yields a sequence which doesn't contain any duplicates. (Admittedly the documentation could be a lot clearer on this point.)

You want:

```
var validName = _name.Where(c => !invalids.Contains(c)).ToArray();
```

Note that you don't need to call `_name.ToCharArray()` as `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`. In other words, you can use:

```
public static string GetValidFilename(string fileNameCandidate)
{
    var invalids = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
    var validName = fileNameCandidate.Where(c => !invalids.Contains(c))
                                     .ToArray();
    return new string(validName);
}
```

Comment: About the `ToCharArray()`, I bet he's using VS2008 that hides extension methods on strings from intellisense...

Comment: @digEmAll: Quite possibly. Fortunately it won't prevent it from actually compiling :)

Answer (score 5):

[Enumerable.Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) produces a "set difference" of two sequence - which means that duplicate characters in the input will be eliminated as well.

What you want is:

```
 _name.Where( x => !invalids.Contains(x) ).ToArray();
```

Since `System.String` is `IEnumerable<char>`, you can simplify this to:

```
var name = fileNameCandidate.Where( x => !invalids.Contains(x) ).ToArray() );
return new string( name );
```

Comment: MSDN says "The set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that do not appear in the second set."

Comment: That's going to produce a `bool[]` rather than a `char[]` for your first snippet, and a compiler error for the second.

Comment: Also, in posted example, "i" and "m" are removed but these letters are not duplicated in original string.

Comment: @e28Makaveli: Indeed, however all LINQ set operators produce distinct results. These are non-contradicting aspects of their behavior.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, you're right of course. I meant to write `Where()` rather than `Select()`. I've corrected that.

Comment: Jon, var validName = _name.Except(invalids).ToArray() produces char[] not bool[].

Comment: @e28Makaveli: Yes, but I was responding to LBushkin's code, not yours. He was using `Select` instead of `Where`.

Comment: @LBushkin: Now it's just the second snippet which won't compile, because there's no `string(IEnumerable<char>)` constructor :)

Comment: @Jon: Thanks :-D ... for some reason I thought there was, but you are correct. I've addressed that as well.

Comment: @Jon: I should have remembered this, actually. It's one of my frustrations that many of the core BCL classes don't yet have overloads or methods that play well with sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously something is going wrong as one 'c' has been removed and not the other! I'd look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885964/regex-to-replace-invalid-characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
return new string(fileNameCandidate.Where(c => !invalids.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```