# Regex to exclude non-word Characters but leave spaces

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to write a `Regex` to stop a use entering invalid characters into a *postcode* field.

from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885992/2987066) I manged to exclude all "Non-word" characters like so.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\W_]+");
string cleanText = regex.Replace(messyText, "").ToUpper();
```

But this also excludes the "Space" characters.

I am sure this is possible but I find regex very confusing!

Can someone help out with an explanation of the regex pattern used?

Comment: What are invalid postcode characters? It sounds like you're in the UK, but many states have some sort of equivalent (with different formats). Do they also need validation?

Comment: Due to the principle of least astonishment, it would also be advisable to ***validate*** rather than *correct*.

Comment: @spender I already **validate** the postcode using a UK postcode regex. But I would also like to stop the user imputting invalid characters as I think it gives a better UX. I assumed that postcodes can only be Alpha-Numeric with an optional space. I may be incorrect though

Comment: I'd argue that preventing certain inputs makes for a worse UX. I'm not alone. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/whats-a-better-user-experience-highlight-errors-or-block-wrong-keystrokes

Comment: @spender Thanks for the link. I will give the UX question a read and consider it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use [character class subtraction](http://regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html?wlr=1):

```
[\W_-[\s]]+
```

It matches one or more non-word and underscore symbols with the exception of **any whitespace characters**.

**To exclude just *horizontal* whitespace characters** use `[\p{Zs}\t]` in the subtraction part:

```
[\W_-[\p{Zs}\t]]+
```

**To exclude just *vertical* whitespace characters (line break chars)** use `[\n\v\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029]` in the subtraction part:

```
[\W_-[\n\v\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029]]+
```

**Non-character class substraction** solution (that is more portable) is

```
[^\w\s]+
```

It matches one or more characters other than word and whitespace characters. Note that this still won't match `_` that are considered word characters (this is important in string tokenization scenarios where `(?:[^\w\s]|_)+` or `[_\W-[\s]]` is preferable).

Answer (score 5):

You can inverse your character class to make it a **negated character class** like this:

```
[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]+
```

This will match any character except a whitespace or alphanumerical character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fklQF/1) (as this is not a .NET regex)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming valid postcodes comprise only alphanumeric character, you may replace with an empty string anything but alphanumerics and spaces:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
string cleanText = regex.Replace(messyText, "").ToUpper();
```

Please note that `\s` includes tabs, newlines and some other non-printable character. You may not want to consider them valid. In this is the case, just list the whitespace character literally:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will capture everything except letters, digits, and spaces.

`[^\w\s\d]|_`

The `^` inside the `[ ]` will cause the regex to look for everything ***except*** letters, digits, and spaces.